# Cisco Nexus vpc card type mismatch

Tags: cisco, vpc, cisco-nexus-5k, cisco-nx-os, fex

I have a pair of Nexus switches configured for vPCs. In several cases, it is working correctly:

```
core01# sh vpc consistency-parameters int po40

    Legend:
        Type 1 : vPC will be suspended in case of mismatch

Name                        Type  Local Value            Peer Value
-------------               ----  ---------------------- -----------------------
mode                        1     active                 active
Speed                       1     1000 Mb/s              1000 Mb/s
Duplex                      1     full                   full
Port Mode                   1     access                 access
MTU                         1     1500                   1500
Admin port mode             1
Shut Lan                    1     No                     No
vPC card type               1     FEX                    FEX
Allowed VLANs               -     1052                   1052
Local suspended VLANs       -     -                      -
```

However, in several cases, it is not:

```
core01# sh vpc consistency-parameters int po60

    Legend:
        Type 1 : vPC will be suspended in case of mismatch

Name                        Type  Local Value            Peer Value
-------------               ----  ---------------------- -----------------------
vPC card type               1     Empty                  FEX
Allowed VLANs               -     1-4094                 1-4094
Local suspended VLANs       -     -                      -
```

On the partner switch, the local and peer values match what core01 reports:

```
core02# sh vpc consistency-parameters int po60

    Legend:
        Type 1 : vPC will be suspended in case of mismatch

Name                        Type  Local Value            Peer Value
-------------               ----  ---------------------- -----------------------
vPC card type               1     FEX                    Empty
Allowed VLANs               -     1-4094                 1-4094
Local suspended VLANs       -     -                      -
```

I haven't been able to figure out why the vPC card type is reporting as Empty.

Any ideas or troubleshooting steps I could try?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or figure it out? Same prob - every line of config is same. Can't figure it out.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is due to a Cisco bug CSCuq60111. Since the bug tool is not for everyone i will post the solution from Cisco here:

Incorrect Type 1 vPC consistency for "vPC card type" in Enhanced vPC
CSCuq60111

**Description**

**Symptom:**

```
show vpc consistency-parameters interface port-channel 

Name                        Type  Local Value            Peer Value             
-------------               ----  ---------------------- -----------------------
vPC card type               1     FEX                    Empty                       -> Peer1 output
vPC card type               1     Empty                  FEX                         -> Peer2 output
OR
vPC card type               1     Empty                   Empty                      -> Peer1 output
vPC card type               1     Empty                   Empty                      -> Peer2 output
```

**Conditions:**

While configuring enhanced vPC on Nexus 6000 for first time or when recent reload has performed on both peers. We may see "vPC card type" Value mismatch on vpc peers. 
- Expected output is

```
Name                        Type  Local Value            Peer Value             
-------------               ----  ---------------------- -----------------------
vPC card type               1     FEX                    FEX                        -> Peer1 output
vPC card type               1     FEX                    FEX                        -> Peer2 output
```

**Workaround:**

- Shut on FEX up-link port-channels on both vPC peers FIRST and then no-shut on both sides.

**Note:**- Fex interfaces will go offline when uplinks are disabled on both vpc peers

**Further Problem Description:**

This behavior **does not affect functionality** of FEX or Host connected to HIF interfaces.